# Can photons scattering off quarks produce resonant states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, atomic-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

In an exam question about photons scattering off protons it showed a resonance graph and asked why there was a lack of structure for energies much higher than the resonance peak. It alluded that the answer had something to do with the fact that at these energies the photons scatter of the constituent quarks rather than the proton as a whole.

Does that mean that, since quarks are elementary particles, there are no resonant states that can be formed from a photon interacting directly with a quark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quarks are most peculiar elementary particles: they cannot be asymptotic states, and be observed in isolation outside hadrons.

So, no, a photon cannot excite them to some type of resonant hadronic bound state. How could it?

(A photon could, and often does, knock them out of the hadron, but they drag the requisite gluons and quarks out with them to generate their own color-singlet hadron cocoon.)

Comment: Because all resonances must correspond to measurable unstable particles (even if not measurable in this particular reaction)?

Comment: Yes, all resonances are basically hadrons (color singlets!)--it's just that they decay too quickly, but that's a quantitative, not qualitative, distinction.

Comment: Does that mean we can say that all resonant states (e.g. of two interacting baryons) are either excited (to a higher angular momentum) states, or rearrangements of the quarks within the composite particles?

Comment: Yes you may say that. Your two options aren't really that different, though. Angular motion is a type of rearrangement. If the net spin of the hadron is different, we call it something else, and not an excited state.  A good review of the quark model details the differing wavefunctions, etc...

Comment: By quark rearrangement I meant more like if we were colliding two compositite particles like a proton and a neturon, a resonant state could be a composite particle/particles composed of different combinations of the quarks (so not still a proton or neutron). So I was suggesting either quarks are rearranged like this in their intermediate state, or their spin/orbital angular momentum are changed/excited?

Comment: You are thinking about resonant dibaryons? These are very, very  rare. You might study the PDG for those...

Comment: Oh are you saying that essentially all common resonances are usually just the initial particles with either their spin angular momenta or orbital angular momenta changed/excited and nothing else really? (That everything else is very rare)

Comment: Yes, essentially, for baryon-baryon scattering. You have no such problem for baryon-meson scattering, or meson-meson resonances.

Comment: Finally, is it not theoretically possible that there could exist resonant states where extra particles have been pair produced? My guess is that maybe this would just never enhance the cross section so it could never be observed as a resonant state, but I’m not sure?

Comment: In QCD, quadrillions of quarks-antiquarks are pair produced and annihilated all the time. You never count particles inside hadrons, beyond the valence quarks. You've  veered off light years form the original question...

Comment: I don’t think so. As I understood it, a resonance is an intermediate state which causes a peak in the cross section for a given reaction and my question was what this intermediate state might ‘look like. From my current knowledge I could not rule out the possibility that intermediate pair production could somehow produce an intermediate state which could decay *so much* easier into the products that it would cause a cross section peak. You have helped me learn that usually the resonances are just excited angular momentum states and rarely they can be dibaryon states, so are they never these?

Comment: Sorry, you want an open tutorial on baryon resonances, and you might try separate questions on each tangent. Dibaryons *never* crop up in photon-proton scattering.

Answer (score 1):

Most hard photons scatter off partons, breaking up the nucleon (per Cosmas Zachos's answer). There is an amplitude for exclusive processes (including a resonance), but it falls rapidly with energy according to "the constituent counting rules". Here you count the point particles in the initial and final states: $n$.

The scattering cross section then scales:

$$ \frac{d\sigma}{dt} \propto \frac 1 {s^{n-2}} $$

so any resonance production will be too tiny to see against the DIS background.

Here's some TJNAF data showing the behavior in $\gamma +D \rightarrow  n+p $ (this reaction has a kinematic region with no background):

[image]

The onset of scaling occurs around $E_{\gamma}=1.5\,$ GeV, where the photon wavelength:

$$ \lambda =\frac{\hbar c}{E_{\gamma}} = \frac{0.2\,{\rm GeV\cdot fm}}{1.5\,{\rm GeV}}=0.13\,{\rm fm}$$

is an order of magnitude smaller than the proton, and the energy is 700 times the binding energy of the deuteron.

If you consider all the reacting hadrons to be Lorentz flattened and time frozen non-interacting disks of quarks, then the constituent counting follow from simple geometric considerations.

Comment: What are these exclusive processes? What is the resonant particle?

Comment: https://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/tables/contents_tables_baryons.html  https://pdg.lbl.gov/2017/reviews/rpp2017-rev-resonances.pdf